# How to tell CKeditor to create new paragraph without any formatting?

Tags: drupal, ckeditor

I create paragraph with class

```
<p class="customclass">...</p>
```

But if I create another paragraph, this class is copied also.

How to tell CKeditor to create new paragraph without any formatting?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant the class is copied when you press the Enter key, you can use the "[enterkey](http://ckeditor.com/addon/enterkey)" plugin and slightly modify its behavior.

First, add the plugin to your ckeditor instance (this is based on the vanilla ckeditor sample page):

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
    extraPlugins: 'enterkey',
    enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_P
});
```

Then edit the plugin.js file under the /plugins/enterkey folder.

Replace this part:

```
if ( !newBlock.getParent() )
   range.insertNode( newBlock );
```

with this:

```
if ( !newBlock.getParent() ) {
    newBlock.removeAttribute('class');
    range.insertNode(newBlock);
}
```

This hack will affect all your new paragraphs so please make sure it works for your scenarios. If there are cases where you prefer the default behavior (preserve previous class and style) you could extend this plugin with further logic.